# Pandas: np.where overwriting values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I currently iterate through the rows of an excel file multiple times and write in "XYZ" to a new column when the row meets certain conditions.

My current code is:

```
 df["new_column"] = np.where(fn == True, "XYZ", "")
```

The issue I face is that when the fn == True condition is not satisfied, I want to do absolutely nothing and move onto checking the next row of the excel file. I noticed that each time I iterate, the empty string replaces the "XYZ"s that are already marked in the file. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Is there something I can do instead of empty string ("") to prevent overwriting?

Edit:

My dataframe is a huge financial Excel file with multiple columns and rows. This data set has columns like quantity, revenue, sales, etc. Basically, I have a list that contains about 50 conditionals. For each condition, I iterate through all the rows in the Excel and for the row that matches the condition, I wanted to put an "XYZ" in the df["new_column"] flagging that row. The df["new_column"] is an added column to the original dataframe. Then, I move onto the next condition up until the 50th conditional.

I think the problem is, is that the way I wrote code replaces the previous existing "XYZ" with empty string when I proceed onto check the other conditionals in the list. Basically, I want to find a way to lock "XYZ" in, so it can't become overwritten.

The fn is a helper function that returns a boolean depending on if the condition equals a row in the dataframe. While I iterate, if the condition matches a row, then this function returns True and marks the df["new_column"] with "XYZ". The helper function takes in multiple arguments to check if the current condition matches any of the rows in the dataframe. I hope this explanation helps!

Comment: I know the name suggests otherwise, but does `df["new_column"]` already exist in the dataframe?

Comment: No it does not!

Comment: That begs the question, what is it overwriting?

Comment: It overwrites the previous "XYZ"s that were already written in the excel file.

Comment: The XYZs in what column?

Comment: In df["new_column"]

Answer (score 1):

you can try using a lambda.

first, create the function:

```
def checkIfTrue(FN, new):
    if new == "":
        pass
    if FN:
        return "XYZ"
```

than apply this to the new column like that:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: checkIfTrue(row["fn"], row["new_column"]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to use `.loc[]`:

```
df.loc[fn, "new_column"] = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: This gives me "cannot use a single bool to index into setitem"

Comment: @BrianKim, could you provide a small sample data sets (`df` and `fn`) and your desired data set?

Comment: I edited my previous response. I hope it's more helpful now!

Comment: @BrianKim, no it didn't make it much clearer. Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.